# ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments 00909. select concat(last_name,' ',job_id) as "Employee and Title" from employees;

Tags: sql, oracle

i keep getting this error. but it goes away when i take away ',' part of the code

Comment: Sometimes, Oracle's syntax errors are misleading and confusing.  This is not one of those times.  The error tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle `concat()` function only allows 2 arguments. Instead use the ANSI SQL `||` compliant concatenation operator:

```
select last_name || ' ' || job_id as "Employee and Title" from employees
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm